# Windows 2-node failover cluster with AD setup

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, failovercluster

Is it possible to create a 2-node failover cluster with AD, but only with 2 physical servers? Creating a failover cluster requires an AD, but sadly I don't have any available hardware to install it.

This is what I have:
1. 2x servers
2. 1x network storage (for iSCSI drives)

For now, I got it working by creating a VM for the AD, then I exported the AD then put it in the other server to achieve redundancy. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Are you using Hyper-V on the physical hosts?

Comment: yes joe, i'm using Hyper-V for the AD while the physical server itself is the cluster node

Comment: Are you clustering the Hyper-V role or another role?

Comment: I am not clustering the Hyper-V role, my Hyper-V is intended to be the AD of the cluster. What I am clustering is for a web server (Apache and MySQL services)

Comment: Have you considered virtualizing the web servers? It seems like a waste of physical resources to install the web server/services on the physical nodes. - At any rate, this should be do-able. You'll want to create a virtual DC on each Hyper-V host. The cluster will need to communicate with a DC in order to come "on line" but even if both Hyper-V hosts are rebooted/started simultaneously the DC's will start automatically (if configured to do so in Hyper-V Manager) and the cluster will come "on line" when communication with a DC is established.

Comment: Incidentally, a Windows Server 2012/2012R2 Failover Cluster supports AD-less bootstrapping, which eliminates the dependency on the DC in order for the cluster to start. - http://blogs.technet.com/b/wincat/archive/2012/08/29/windows-server-2012-failover-cluster-enhanced-integration-with-active-directory-ad.aspx

Comment: Thanks joe, do you have any guides for this virtualization? Is this the same as putting it on a Hyper-V client instead?

Also, about the 2 virtual DCs, should they be mirror copies?

Comment: There's plenty of Hyper-V "how-to" documentation available. You could start by visiting TechNet. I don't understand what you mean by this `Is this the same as putting it on a Hyper-V client instead?` - What are you referring to? As to the Domain Controllers, I'm not sure what you mean by `mirror image` but you would and should have 2 Domain Controllers for your Ad domain. One DC on one Hyper-V host and the other DC on the other Hyper-V host. DC1 and DC2, for example.

Comment: What I mean by `putting it on a Hyper-V client` is the transferring of the cluster to a Hyper-V client, is that the same as virutalization? My current setup right now is that I have virtual DCs for each server, but also an AD for each of them, that makes it 2 ADDCs. Should I remove the other AD so that only 1 will exist?

Comment: Yes, putting it on a Hyper-V client is what I mean in the sense that you'll create two new virtual machines in Hyper-V to be your web servers. Virtual machines are typically called guests or virtual machines, not clients. As for AD, I'm still not understanding you. You need 1 AD domain with 2 Domain Controllers. You should run one DC on one host and the other DC on the other host.

Comment: I get it now, but i'm afraid I can't virtualize it anymore because the setup is already in production. But I'll keep it in mind (for future projects). As for the AD, your answer is perfect, which means I only need to have 1 AD, one question though: any suggestions on where should I put the AD? Is it possible to put it in the network drive?